# What is the best way to display images on a website?

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, user-interface

I can't find this information anywhere. But what is the optimal aspect ratio for images for the web? I want images to scale nicely regardless of size but I always end up with this issue (check the fiddle link):

[http://jsfiddle.net/28QAt/](https://jsfiddle.net/28QAt/)

```
<p>How to display any sized image nicely?</p>
```

[image]
<sub>(source: [placehold.it](https://placehold.it/468x127))</sub>

    
    
    [image]

I don't want to set a height and width because images could look stretched and out of shape and I don't have anyway to crop images to the right size. so i'm wondering how to best handle any size images with CSS or Jquery and make them look good when they are side by side.

Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about design and is opinion based

Comment: I want to know if someone has had a solution that i haven't thought of yet so it's a good question that others including myself can learn from

Comment: You've put your question on the wrong place. You shouldn't count on programming geeks to give you any good opinion on design.

Comment: Don't answer then i'm waiting for a CSS or Jquery guru to answer

Comment: *"What is the best way…"* questions are ___always___ opinion based (although this statement is also based on my opinion ;)).

Comment: @V0X - What you are looking for is an SVG (Scalable Vector Graphics) image format.  Take a look at [this article](http://css-tricks.com/using-svg/) on how to use SVG on CSS Tricks.

Answer (score 3):

From this quote: **I don't have anyway to crop images to the right size**

Use `max-width: 100%;` for the image.

Comment: Cant use max-width as I want my images to only be 120px wide. but depending on the orientation and size it looks crap when i have a few images on my site

Comment: if your picture is of maximum of width 120px then setting max-width will be upto 120px which is 100%.

Answer (score 0):

It's a lot on the idea of man. Is it possible to keep an eye on using CSS

```
min-height/width , max-height/width
```

or use an already created Jquery plugin

[Demo](http://www.ryanepp.com/demos/balanced_gallery/horizontal)

[Tutorial](https://github.com/repp/BalancedGallery)